# TexShop localization issue

Tags: texshop

Once upon a time, I installed and ran TeXShop in an OS X system where French was selected as the main language. Then, I removed French as preferred language in the SysPrefs, and left only English.

As far as I can tell, all my previously French-localised apps gladly made the move to English -- save for TeXShop that stubbornly refuses to switch.

I've removed the app from the system, deleted preference (.plist) files everywhere I could find them, ... to no avail. Every time I launch it, I see those pesky French menus. (and of course, I've logged out then in)

Any pointers to how to cleanly fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: This may not be just a TeXShop problem. I set my main language to German a while ago Mail.app still shows German flag colours even though the main menus are all in English.

Comment: Well, after more tries, I gave in, turned off my paranoid "don't use random software downloaded from random corners of the internet" module, and used Language Switcher (http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/). It worked like a charm. Now I only need to understand how Language Switcher operated its magic :-)